# SQLite with DI freezing the UI

Tags: c#, sqlite, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, winui-3

I am trying to implement SQLite with IOC DI in a WinUI 3 app. I have created a [minimal github project](https://github.com/tinmac/SQLite_DI/tree/master) that demonstrates the issue.

The UI freezes & is intermittant, it can take a while to reproduce (approx 1 in 50 runs, proved on multiple PCs). This is the frustration & im hoping an obvious error in my code can be identified instead of having to run it that many times.

I expect that ive made a mistake and need help to identify the issue with the pattern that I have adopted.

App.cs

```
private IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddDbContext<SQLite_DbContext>(options => options
        .UseSqlite($"{DbConString}")
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
        .EnableDetailedErrors()
    ); 

    services.AddTransient<IPersonDb, PersonSQLiteDb>();

    services.AddSingleton<Main_VM>();

    var svcs = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    return svcs;
}

protected async override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();
    m_window.Activate();

    using (var db = new SQLite_DbContext())
    {
        await db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
    }
}
```

Db Context

```
public class SQLite_DbContext : DbContext
{
    public SQLite_DbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(App.DbConString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

SQLite Db Person CRUD

```
public Task<List<Person>> GetAll()
{
    using (db = new SQLite_DbContext())
    {
        return db.People.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
}

public async Task<Person> Insert(Person item)
{
    try
    {
        using (db = new SQLite_DbContext())
        {
            await db.People.AddAsync(item);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return item;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Main ViewModel

```
public Main_VM(IPersonDb personDb)
{
    _PersonDb = personDb;
}

public async Task LoadDb()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Loading Db...");

    var people = await _PersonDb.GetAll();

    PeopleOC = new ObservableCollection<Person>(people);

    PersonCount = $"{PeopleOC.Count} records";
}
```

please see github minimal [project](https://github.com/tinmac/SQLite_DI/tree/master)

Why does it intermittently freeze?

Comment: I don't reproduce any problems, maybe you should try to make it more prominent. PS: sqlite is not async intenally, so I'm not sure it's useful to use async methods on it (not saying this is the cause of your problems)

Comment: When a freeze happens, either do one of two things: 1. Hit `Break All` during debugging in Visual Studio. 2. Go to the Windows task manager, right click the application process and select `Create dump file`. After the dump file is created, you can load it in Visual Studio. Both options allow you to inspect at what position the application is currently hanging; you can inspect the stack trace. You can post such stack trace here if you can't figure this out by yourself.